# Repeatedly wake up, perform task, hibernate for hardware troubleshooting

Tags: windows-7, power, hibernate

I'm currently trying to prove a hardware malfunction to the hardware vendor. The system occasionally performs a hard shutdown (like a power loss), with batteries fully loaded.

The problem *seems* to be best reproducable within the first 5 minutes of waking up from hibernation and while performing system intensive tasks, so I would like to record the laptop during the following procedure:

```
repeat {

* Hibernate
* Wake up, perform system intensive task for 10 minutes

}
```

Any ideas on how to get this done?

---

Progress:

I've now completed the following setup:

- Manually send to hibernate
- Manually wake from hibernate
- perform AOGenMark for 20 times via batch loop (thanks moses)
- go back to hibernation after batch file is completed via wosb (thanks martineau)

So the whole cycle has now been boiled down to manually start the process and wake from hibernate. That's close enough for me, using a mouse every 10-15 minutes is fine.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: So you want to monitor the performance of the laptop during this time?

Comment: I don't actually care about the performance during this time. I would like to create a continous cycle of wake hibernation -> continous system intensive task for about 10 minutes -> hibernate -> wake from hibernation.

Comment: I recently ran across something called [WakeupOnStandBy](http://dennisbabkin.com/wosb/) which sounds like it could do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, WOSB is a nice solution to a part of the problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [AOGenMark](http://www.geeks3d.com/20110513/aogenmark-1-3-0-simple-multi-core-cpu-benchmark/), a command line tool for multi-core CPU benching. Run it from a batch after calling a hibernation, and it will finish on wake:

```
@echo off
c:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Hibernate
"C:\Users\Sauron\Desktop\AOGenMArk-1.3.0\AOGenMark.exe"
```

Comment: I would use a powershell script to do the same thing, only because it would loop very easy.